# How to make FeignClient fail on startup when SpEl expression resolves to null

Tags: spring, spring-el, feign

I'm making use of `FeignClient` in what I hope is a simple manner like

```
@GetMapping(value = "${some.expression.resolved.from.application.yml}", produces = "application/json")
int getSomething();
```

I'd like to make the application fail its startup in the case when `some.expression.resolved.from.application.yml` cannot be resolved, in order to `fail-fast`, like it happens with Spring's `Value` annotation for example.

However, even though the property does not exist anywhere, the startup succeeds (and the app fails later on, when I try to invoke `getSomething` because of the missing URL piece)